# Gerar lista/matriz trazendo todas combinações de n elementos tomados p a p em python 3

Tags: python, combinações

Exemplo: A B C D   4 elementos
resultado:
COM DOIS ELEMENTOS
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD

COM TRÊS ELEMENTOS
ABC
ABD
ACD
BCD

Answer (score 1):

**Aqui está:**

```
from itertools import permutations
import re

caracteres = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in permutations(caracteres,2): # 2 elementos
    i = re.sub(r'\W',"",str(i)) # Retirando outros caracteres que não sejam letras
    print(i)

print()
for i in permutations(caracteres,3): # 3 Elementos
    i = re.sub(r'\W',"",str(i))
    print(i)

print()
for i in permutations(caracteres,4): # 4 Elementos
    i = re.sub(r'\W',"",str(i))
    print(i)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Antony,

Comment: Eu fiz uma mudança de permutations para combinations e resultou no que eu precisava!

Comment: Como eu faria para que a coleção de objetos -caracteres e o tamanho do agrupamento  fosse solicitada para o usuario digitar?